# HTML "Div" cannot show full height on small monitors

Tags: html, css

I have 2 monitors. The one is 24" and the other is my laptop's monitor (12.5"). A "div" (red box) in my web application can be shown on big monitor full height, but just part of it on my small monitor.

My question is why it displays differently on different size of monitor? Because all height settings in my css are percentage and I never used absolute number for the height. Why does the red box (div id is "scrollTable") show differently on different size of monitor? Because this issue, the dynamic table in this "div" cannot be shown completely even if the div is scrolled to the bottom. The row number of the dynamic table depends on Users' search result, maybe only 1 or 2 rows or maybe more than 30 or 40 rows sometimes. Please see the css and html below. Thanks for your help.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  height: 6%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0.2px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: central;
  background: #8a1841;
  color: papayawhip;
  display: block;
}

#nsmap {
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 94%;
}

#searchPanel {
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
  height: 94%;
  width: 20%
}

#HomeButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}

label {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

table.imagetable {}

table.imagetable tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

table.imagetable th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

table.imagetable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #92c8da;
}

table.imagetable tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #EBECCD;
}

.cboWidth {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
}

.ccTable1 {
  height: 77%;
}

#scrollTable {
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-height: 80%;
  min-height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#StreetKey {
  width: 100%;
}

.thirty {
  width: 30%;
}

.twenty {
  width: 20%;
}

.fifteen {
  width: 15%;
}

thead {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dijitButtonNode {
  width: 160px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: hidden;
}

.dijitButtonNode:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 52%;
  width: 45%;
}

#tbPrint {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.tdPrint {
  border: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-width: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
}

#trPrint {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title> Online Map Book </title>

  <header>
    <h4>Online Map Guide Book</h4>
  </header>

  <div id="nsmap" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
  </div>
  <div id="searchPanel">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12.5px">Select Electoral District:</label> <br>

      <select id="EDNum" name="EDNum" class="cboWidth"></select>
      <br><br>
      <label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12.5px">
            Select Polling Division: </label><br>
      <select id="PDNum" name="PDNum" style="border:1px solid #000000"></select>
      <br><br>

      <div class="dropdown" style="width:100px">
        <table id="tbPrint">
          <tr>
            <td><label style="font-size:12.5px">Print map or street key:</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="trPrint">
            <td class="tdPrint">
              <button id="btnPrintGroup" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" disabled>
                                    Print
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div id="btnPrint"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>
                    <div class="dijitButtonNode" id="btnStKey" onclick="printStKey()" style="margin-left:10px">
                      Street Key
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div id="StreetKey" class="ccTable1">
      <div style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold"> Street Key </div>

      <div id="scrollTable">
        <table id="streetTable" class="imagetable " style="cursor: pointer;">
          <colgroup>
            <col class="thirty" />
            <col class="twenty" />
            <col class="fifteen" />
            <col class="fifteen" />
            <col class="twenty" />
          </colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Street</th>
              <th>Town</th>
              <th>Low No.</th>
              <th>High No.</th>
              <th>Order</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that? - https://ibb.co/HzpvPb3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use 100% it means that you take the whole heigth os the div's parent. If you want to show your div always in the viewport, try using this units : `vh`
They mean: viewport height, so if you set the `height:100vh`, the div will always be fit to the viewport no matter what screen. :)

https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: Sorry for the late. Thanks for your answer. It is working!